# fluorescent light wiring in garage

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a 4 foot fluorescent light that I want to hang in my garage for better lighting. I have an outlet on the ceiling next to my garage opener that I know I can use the power from.
The question I have is, instead of opening up my drywall and fishing wires across the ceiling, would it be safe if I used the PVC wiring duct covers (reference the the photo attached)?

Also what would be the best kind of wiring for this project?

[image: referenced photot]

Answer (score 2):

Generally if a thing is *installed*, it can't have a flexible plug-in cord.  However, there's an exception for luminaires; it is permissible there. Don't make it super obvious; don't use an extension cord for instance.  If you need a receptacle closer to your light, you can extend off existing receptacles (i.e. for your garage door opener).

You can't use just any cable tray for this purpose.  Most of them are intended for ethernet cable, USB and the like.   You need to use surface-mount conduit that is UL/CSA/TUV listed and rated for power cables.

For extending hard-wired circuits, proper surface-mount conduit *is a thing* and it is sold at local big-box stores.  However the systems have many parts, and the big-box stores have computerized inventory systems and they don't stock the parts that don't sell well. This always leaves me in the lurch.  You are much better off going to a proper electrical supply house, where they will stock all the parts for that particular system.  Buy it all there.